# Why does this f# function expects an integer[] instead of byte array

Tags: f#

Could someone please show me why the  function  below  expects integer[] instead of byte[]

```
type Node =
    | InternalNode of int*Node*Node
    | LeafNode of int * byte

let weight node =
    match node with 
    |InternalNode(w,_,_) -> w
    |LeafNode(w,_)-> w

let createNodes inputValues =
    let getCounts (leafNodes:(int*byte)[])= 
        inputValues |>Array.iter
            (fun b-> let (w,v) =leafNodes.[(int)b]
                     leafNodes.[(int)b]<-(w+1,v))

        leafNodes
    [|for b in 0uy..255uy -> (0 ,b)|] |>getCounts
    |>List.ofArray
    |>List.map LeafNode
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only place that tells the F# compiler something about the type of the parameter is inside the lambda function given to `Array.iter` (from the use of this higher-order function, the compiler infers that you're working with arrays). Inside the lambda function you have:

```
leafNodes.[(int)b]
```

As a side-note, `int` in this code is just a normal F# function (not a special type cast construct), so the usual way to write it would be just:

```
leafNodes.[int b]
```

Now, the compiler knows that `b` (that is, values of the array given as the argument) can be converted to integer, however the `int` function works with other types (you can write for example `int 3.13f`. In ambiguous cases like this, the compiler uses `int` as the default type, so that's the reason why you're seeing a type `int[]`.

You can add type annotations to the declaration like this (and it will work without any other changes, because `byte` can be converted to integer using the `int` function):

```
let createNodes (inputValues:byte[]) =  
  // ...
```

Comment: Great explanation from the writer of the best f# book. thanx :)